Find if cell contents exist in array
I am trying to find a solution so that if the contents of B2 can be found in array DOUBLE!A2:A, it would output B2, else it would output "Cannot be doubled".
I tried =IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, DOUBLE!A2:A), B2, "Cannot be doubled") but it is not working.
Here is an example sheet
Thank you in advance. Hopefully my question is clear enough.

Two points here:

The syntax is REGEXMATCH(text, regular_expression). Your sytanx should have been REGEXMATCH(cell to be searched, search value). You have interchanged it.

Also, the first argument "text" for your formula can only be a single-cell range like C1 or E3.


